# Parse Int not executing when entered in the loop

Tags: javascript, html, parseint

Parse Int not executed. I can not figure out why this issue is arising.

```
function compute(){
    var totalDis = document.getElementById("totaldisplay");
    var htmlDis = "";
    htmlDis+="<table><tr><th>Student Name</th><th>Total Mark</th>";
    for(var row=0;row<names.length;row++)
    {
        var valMrk = document.querySelectorAll("#row" + row + ".stdMrk");
        var totalval = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<=5;i++)
        {
            totalval += parseInt(valMrk[i].Value);
            //alert("testing compute function");
        }   
        htmlDis += "<tr id='row" + i +"'><td style='border:1px solid black;'>"+names[row]+"</td><td style='border:1px solid black;'>"+totalval+"</td>";

    }
    htmlDis+="</table>";
    totalDis.innerHTML=htmlDis;
}
```

According to the code above, the function stops executing when the function enters the loop and stops at the parse int step, which is annoying because, on another form, it works fine with the same code with just a few modifications of variables.

Why is this issue arising?

(Edited according to answer)
this is the loop that generate the input box and the above codes is supposed to compute each row but after making the changes, the row is displaying but not computing, only displaying 0 for each row.

Here are the codes for the loop generating the textboxes.

```
for(j=0;j<names.length;j++)
    {
        html+="<tr><td style='border:1px solid grey;'>"+names[j]+"</td>";
        for(i = 0; i<num_of_ica; i++)
        {

            html+="<td><input type='text' class='stdMrk' placeholder='0' value='0' /></td>";
        }
        for(var k=1;k<=1;k++)//display project or final exams txt box
        {
            html+= "<td><input type='text' class='stdMrk' placeholder='0' value='0' /></td>";

        }

        html+="</tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Obviously `valMrk.length` is less than 5 so in the loop it reaches to index that does not exist and it generates error. change it like this (also make sure that all values can be parsed as int):

```
var valMrk = document.querySelectorAll("#row" + row + ".stdMrk");
    var totalval = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<valMrk.length;i++)
    {
        if(!isNaN(valMrk[i].Value)
        totalval += parseInt(valMrk[i].Value);
        //alert("testing compute function");
    }
```

Comment: @KrishnaRamdin I edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: when i add the if condition in the loop, the function itself does not execute.

Comment: @KrishnaRamdin I had a typo which I have corrected it, it should be i`sNaN` not `isNan`

Comment: it is still not adding the numbers and displaying 0 for each rows of names..help...Basically i have a set of input tag which get generated via a for loop then this function should add those numbers according to their names and display the added numbers beside the names.